# Use of a time integrator to find a matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Under what conditions can we use a time integrator (ODE solver) to find matrix inverse?  Specifically, say we have a linear system $Ax=b$.  Under some conditions on $A$, we can rewrite this equation as
$$
\dot{x} + Ax = b
$$
and then apply a numerical method to solve for $x$.  For example, we can use a forward Euler scheme to generate the iteration
$$
x_{k+1} = x_k + \Delta t(-Ax_k + b)
$$
In terms of code, the following MATLAB/Octave script demonstrates that this works

```
% Set the size                                                                  
m = 5;                                                                          

% Set the number of iterations
niter = 100000;

% Set the timestep
dt = 0.001;

% Find the operator and rhs                                                     
A = randn(m);                                                                   
b = randn(m,1);   
A = triu(A) + triu(A,1)';
[v d]=eig(A);
d = rand(m,1)*100;
A = v*diag(d)*v';

% Find the initial guess                                                        
x = zeros(m,1);                                                                 

% Run the iteration                                                             
for i=1:niter                                                                   
    x = x + dt*(-A*x+b);                                                        
end                                                                             

% Find the residual                                                             
xtrue = A\b;                                                                    
fprintf('|| x - xtrue ||: %e\n',norm(x-xtrue)); 

> test01
|| x - xtrue ||: 1.551632e-16
```

Now, of course it doesn't always work.  From what I can tell, it works for symmetric matrices where the eigenvalues are positive.  That said, I don't have a proof nor better conditions when it should or not occur.  As such, under what conditions for $A$ is this valid?  Further, why does this work under some situations?

Comment: A first remark is that the phenomena is visibly based on the fact that $\dot{x}$ tends to $0$ when $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Your ODE $\dot{x}=-Ax+b$ will converge to the equilibrium point given by $b-Ax=0$ if the system is **asymptotically stable** that is, if all eigenvalues of $-A$ have negative real parts.

Comment: In order to take profit of what @Dmitry just said you, you should transform your affine diff. equation into a linear one by setting $A^{-1}b=c$ (we assume $A$ square and invertible). Thus $\dot{x}=-Ax+b$ becomes $\dot{x}-\dot{c}=-Ax+Ac$. Setting $y:=x-c$, we obtain  $\dot{y}=-Ay$ which is a canonical form.